# parent table with multiple child insertion using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, insertion

i've created an application which uses hibernate inheritance and mapping.
There is a parent class named Payment and Child class called Credit.
Right i'm trying to insert multiple child values for one single parent id.
Like as shown below

`````````````````````````````````
|``````````````|
|    Payment   |
|--------------|
| id  |  nane  |
|-----|--------|
|  1  |  mod 1 |
|-----|--------|
|  2  |  mod 2 |
|-----|--------|


|````````````````````````````````|
|              Credit            |     
|--------------------------------|
| id  |  payid | type  |  mode   |
|-----|--------|-------|---------|
|  1  |   1    |   1   |   m1    |
|-----|--------|-------|---------|
|  2  |   1    |   4   |   m6    |
|-----|--------|-------|---------|
|  3  |   1    |   5   |   m5    |
|-----|--------|-------|---------|
|  4  |   1    |   1   |   m7    |
|-----|--------|-------|---------|
`````````````````````````````````

My code is as given below (**For mapping and other details you can check** [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834618/does-hibernate-using-both-inheritance-and-hibernate-mapping-will-cause-any-drawb))

```
Payment tabletcstatus=new Payment();
    tabletcstatus.setName("name 123");
    session.save(tabletcstatus);


    Credit c=new Credit();
    c.setMode("mode 1");
    c.setPayid(tabletcstatus);
    session.save(c);


    Credit c1=new Credit();
    c1.setMode("mode 2");
    c1.setPayid(tabletcstatus);
    session.save(c1);
```

But when i execute i'm getting the following executed

```
Hibernate: insert into hhh.payment (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into hhh.payment (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into credit (type, mode, payid) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into hhh.payment (name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into credit (type, mode, payid) values (?, ?, ?)
```

here payment is inserted thrice and the two credit has different payid

can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

Comment: You will have to show us the hibernate mappings. Thanks

Comment: its there in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834618/does-hibernate-using-both-inheritance-and-hibernate-mapping-will-cause-any-drawb

Comment: I think inheritance is causing problem.try without inheritance

Comment: sir but we need inheritance.....i'm using both inheritance and mapping..... can u please tell me the problem???

Answer (score 1):

Well your mapping is somewhat 'exotic' in that you have Credit extends Payment and Payment also has a collection of credits. Not something I have come across but I guess, if this is really what you want, then it should work.

Regarding the first issue, how many entries would you expect in payments? You create three 'payments' 1 x Payment and 2 x Credits and are using a Joined Table strategy so 3 insertions is exactly right.

Comment: but i need payment (parent) to be inserted once and for that id i need multiple credits (child)

Comment: Then revise your mappings. Remove the inheritance so that  Payment has a collection of credits and Credit IS NOT as payment. 3 insertions to payment is exactly correct for your current mappings.

Comment: sir can we do that using inheritance .......and without mapping....... still i'm in a bit confusion whether inheritance or mapping which is better......